# How to use xsl to find the elements more than two

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML in here ,

```
<papers>
        <paper>
            <title>title1</title>
            <id>12</id>
            <date>1991</date>
            <number_of_pages>number_of_pages1</number_of_pages>
            <price>123</price>
        </paper>

        <paper>
            <title>title2</title>
            <id>12</id>
            <date>1992</date>
            <number_of_pages>number_of_pages2</number_of_pages>
            <price>111</price>
        </paper>

        <paper>
            <title>title3</title>
            <id>6</id>
            <date>1993</date>
            <number_of_pages>number_of_pages3</number_of_pages>
            <price>121</price>
        </paper>        

        <paper>
            <title>title4</title>
            <id>12</id>
            <date>1994</date>
            <number_of_pages>number_of_pages4</number_of_pages>
            <price>212</price>
        </paper>

        <paper>
            <title>title5</title>
            <id>24</id>
            <date>1995</date>
            <date>number_of_pages5</date>
            <number_of_pages>number_of_pages4</number_of_pages>
            <price>231</price>
        </paper>    

    </papers>
```

As you see , there are 3 papers id equals to 12 , 
I don't know how to write a XSL to show the paper' information which have the same ids more than 2 .

Comment: **1.** Please post the resulting code you are hoping to achieve. **2.** This is a fairly frequent question: do a search for "Muenchian grouping".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to write a `<xsl:for-each>` or `<xsl:apply-templates>` for displaying all the paper informations where paper id is equal to 12

Below is the XPATH to retrieve paper information

```
/papers/paper[id=12]
```

Based on above information, you do some effort.

If you stuck, you can post another question with more information on what you tried and achieved so far.

Comment: This question is about elements "which have the same ids", not elements "which have an id of 12". There is no basis to assume neither that the id is known in advance, nor that there will be only one such id.